# Nutch on Hadoop | Input path does not exist:

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, nutch, hadoop2

I am getting the error Input path does not exist when I run the command

```
nutch inject crawldb urls
```

In nutch/logs I got this error in hadoop.log

```
2015-08-16 16:08:12,834 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: starting at 2015-08-16 16:08:12
2015-08-16 16:08:12,834 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: crawlDb: crawldb
2015-08-16 16:08:12,835 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: urlDir: urls
2015-08-16 16:08:12,835 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
2015-08-16 16:08:13,296 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-08-16 16:08:13,417 WARN  snappy.LoadSnappy - Snappy native library not loaded
2015-08-16 16:08:13,430 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:hdravi cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/hdravi/urls
2015-08-16 16:08:13,432 ERROR crawl.Injector - Injector: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/hdravi/urls
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1081)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:323)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)
```

It some how searches in local file system.

This is the content of hadoop's core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

This is the content hadoop's hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

When I type `hadoop fs -ls -R /` , this is the output I get

```
drwxrwxrwx   - hdravi supergroup          0 2015-08-16 16:06 /user
drwxrwxrwx   - hdravi supergroup          0 2015-08-16 16:06 /user/hdravi
drwxr-xr-x   - hdravi supergroup          0 2015-08-16 16:06 /user/hdravi/urls
-rw-r--r--   1 hdravi supergroup        240 2015-08-16 16:06 /user/hdravi/urls/seed.txt
```

Am I missing any configuration in hadoop/nutch?

**UPDATE**

I get the following error when I use the complete HDFS path

```
2015-08-16 23:33:22,876 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: starting at 2015-08-16 23:33:22
2015-08-16 23:33:22,877 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: crawlDb: crawldb
2015-08-16 23:33:22,877 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: urlDir: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hdravi/user/hdravi/urls
2015-08-16 23:33:22,878 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
2015-08-16 23:33:23,317 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-08-16 23:33:23,410 WARN  snappy.LoadSnappy - Snappy native library not loaded
2015-08-16 23:33:23,762 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:hdravi cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
2015-08-16 23:33:23,764 ERROR crawl.Injector - Injector: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1081)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:323)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)
```

Comment: I am getting new exception when I use the complete hdfs path. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about nutch, but regarding Hadoop try loading the configuration files using the configuration object before starting the MapReduce job.

This solution works with me:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();        
conf.addResource(new Path("path to hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("path to hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

You may also give it a try with the full path of the input directory

```
hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hdravi
```